# localhost.com redirects to google search

Tags: url, web, browser, dns, localhost

I am eager to know why [localhost.com](http://localhost.com) (without www) redirects  to google.com. I also noticed that [www.localhost.com](http://www.localhost.com) gives a 404 page not found. I checked this in Firefox, Chrome and Internet Explorer all does the same. I checked the domain name records and it shows it belongs to Tucows and I am pretty sure Google doesn't own it and I know we can use http redirect to change it to a www or non-www version as the site owner wishes.

Answer (score 18):

Interesting answer posted by Ken Watford, Google employee: http://www.quora.com/Why-does-http-localhost-com-redirect-to-Google

He claims someone bought the domain when the web was still young and kept it ever since, but he does not say who.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like others have had the results as you, check out the links below.
Try here:
http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20111105050333AATP1r5

or here:
http://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/146474-localhost-redirects-to-googlecom/

Answer (score 1):

I think localhost.com should be owned by google as I tried pinging it and it showed the ip of google.com.I still don't know why the DNS records shows tucows as the owner.

Comment: Regarding *"I still don't know why the DNS records shows tucows as the owner"*, **because** it **is** registered through Tucows. Will your domain be Google's property if you simply redirect your dns to google's ip?

Comment: @Pacerier I don't think any one in their right mind would do that after getting a very popular domain name like local host.com.

Comment: Likely someone who is pretty busy with something else and is just camping on that domain name for the time being. Actually, it's likely that this person is working in Google too.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using the Windows platform, then go to your `%windir%\System32\drivers\etc` and copy the `host` file to `%userprofile%\Desktop`. Open it with any text editor and remove the `#` sign from the front of `127.0.0.1 localhost`. Save it and paste it back. Check if the problem is solved.

Answer (score -1):

I have been searching this from long and finally i found complete solution after going through different answers.

As far as @pradeep's answer is concern, he is right that localhost.com is purchased and points to particular IP so it is redirecting.

But we can override domain names in Windows platform for our local development PC via hosts file residing in C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc as per @Faysal's answer.

Open hosts file as administrator and enter following line

127.0.0.1      localhost.com

But doing such also did not solve my problem. So i found final solution which will work in chrome browser.

In chrome you have to clear all dns cache via opening following url

chrome://net-internals/#dns

And here clear all cache and finally you will be redirect localhost.com to your local server's home page.

Answer (score -2):

`localhost.com` is a website. It does not point to your local IP, instead it most likely has an `A record` pointing to Google's IP. It practically is Google, and I can prove it.

When the site worked if you connected using HTTPS then it would give a certificate error, the reason being that the certificate is signed to `google.com` but `localhost.com` is connecting.

I think the site has now been removed though.... I hope that solves it. It can cause some confusion since `localhost` points to `127.0.0.1`.